# Pandas add monthly average to a column

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my dataframe.

```
   index     y
6/17/2018   100
6/24/2018   200
7/1/2018    100
7/8/2018    200
7/15/2018   300
   …         …
```

The desired dataframe would be:

```
index        y  MonthlyAverage
6/17/2018   100 150
6/24/2018   200 150
7/1/2018    100 200
7/8/2018    200 200
7/15/2018   300 200
…            …  …
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `to_period('M')` to transform the dates into months and group by those

```
df['index'] = pd.to_datetime(df['index'])
df['MonthlyAverage'] = (df.groupby(df['index'].dt.to_period('M'))
                          ['y'].transform('mean')
                       )
```

Output:

```
       index    y  MonthlyAverage
0 2018-06-17  100             150
1 2018-06-24  200             150
2 2018-07-01  100             200
3 2018-07-08  200             200
4 2018-07-15  300             200
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First we need convert the index to datetime by `to_datetime`, then we do `transform`

```
df['index']=pd.to_datetime(df.index,format='%m/%d/%Y')
df['mean']=df.groupby(df['index'].dt.strftime('%Y%d')).y.transform('mean')
df
```